# How to split an unlocked package already in production in two unlocked packages?

Tags: salesforcedx

We currently have two unlocked packages in production, and one of them is becoming too large and it also depends on managed packages. It is therefore too slow to develop and install it and we would like to split package A in two packages, B and C, with C depending on B.

Splitting the source code is not difficult however, given the metadata components are already deployed in production org, when I will try to install C, it will say its metadata component are already a part of A. On the other side, if I instead of having B and C I use a new version of A as a replacement for B, installing the new version of A will not remove fields but will remove flows and other metadata.

What's a reasonable process to follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the items you want in Package B from Package A in your repository. Create a new version of Package A, and install using the `--upgradetype DeprecateOnly` option. At this point, the removed items will appear as "Deprecated" in the org. Now, install Package B. The metadata will be associated to the new package. Package B and C are not strictly necessary, as you can have Package A become your hypothetical Package B, and the new Package B will become your hypothetical Package C.